# How to insert Java data on the MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I'm having an error while running this code. I don't know why. I just want to make a method that when called will store data on MySQL database.
Here's the code:

```
public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, 
                String userID, String userPassword, String role)
{
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotelmanagementsystem",                            "some_user","");

        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("Insert into employee(Firstname, Lastname, UserID, UserPassword, Role)values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?");    
        statement.setString(1, firstName);
        statement.setString(2, lastName);
        statement.setString(3, userID);
        statement.setString(4, userPassword);
        statement.setString(5, role);
        statement.executeUpdate();

        con.close(); 
    }
    catch( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();        
        return;
    }
}
```

Console : Syntax Error

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("Insert into employee(Firstname, Lastname, UserID, UserPassword, Role)values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?");
```

to

```
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("Insert into employee(Firstname, Lastname, UserID, UserPassword, Role)values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

You were missing the Closing Bracket `)`

Comment: @juergend, I did explain it saying "You were missing the Closing Bracket )"

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the closing paranthesis of values(.

Answer (score 1):

```
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("Insert into employee(Firstname, Lastname, UserID, UserPassword, Role)values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?");
```

should be

```
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("Insert into employee(Firstname, Lastname, UserID, UserPassword, Role)values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

you were missing closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Add a double quote to your query and then it will be fine.

```
    PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("Insert into employee(Firstname, Lastname, UserID, UserPassword, Role)values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```